# Why is my terminal starting with $?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a crontab that runs a shell Script.
The shell script contains codes to create tmux and launch some commands.

```
@reboot /home/netforce/scripts/script.sh > /dev/null
```

The Following is contents of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sess=erp

if [ "`tmux ls | grep $sess`" != "" ]  ; then

   echo "session $sess already running"
   exit 1
fi

echo "starting session"

tmux new-session -d -s erp
tmux rename-window 'server'
tmux send-keys 'supervise ~/svc/netforce' 'C-m'
sleep 2
```

Well things do work , tmux is created and software is running .

But is running with

```
$ ./run.py
```

It should be running as

```
netforce@netforce-computer:~/netforce$ ./run.py
```

Why i want to run as above?
It works okay for the main run comand but. I have multiple windows eg for print that use shell script (and it doesnot work)

When i run the `script.sh` manually it works perfectly though.

From little research i came to know the bash profile is not loaded. But i have no clue how to launch with my bash environment (.bashrc ? i suppose).

Any suggestion is very much appreicated.

**UPDATE**

My updated crontab is

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

@reboot sleep 60 && /home/netforce/asus_scripts/start-erp.sh > /dev/null
#* */4 * * * /home/netforce/backup/backup_db.py
```

Some python files are working but some have issue due to the bash.
When i `echo $0` i receive `-bash` . This is not my normal bash .

When i open a new terminal and type `echo $0` i receive `-bash` (This is correct).And the python files are working correctly. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it running bash without your bashrc, or is it actually running sh (perhaps inherited from cron's default `$SHELL`?) What does `echo $0` say?

Comment: @steeldriver well , it does have the shebang line in the script itself, right ?

Comment: @Serg yes - but merely executing a bash script doesn't set `$SHELL` afaik (try adding `bash -c '/usr/bin/env > $HOME/cronenv'` to your crontab for example)

Comment: @steeldriver , yes it is running without bashrc (probably it is not loaded )
so i managed somehow using `@reboot sleep 60 && home /home/XXX/start-erp.sh > /dev/null` . Now i do get my `netforce@netforce-computer` but i ran into another issue where some python file is not executed. 

I tried to do  `echo $0` i get `-bash` (this is not correct )
When i open a new terminal and do  `echo $0` i get `bash` (Correct one ) this is really confusing .any suggestions ? I will update my crontab codes.

Comment: AFAIK `-bash` *is* correct - for a bash *login* shell

Comment: Yes  `bash` seems to be okay. 
I had issue as `Error cant connect display`. 
Fixed this by adding `export DISPLAY=:0; tmux send-keys 'supervise ~/svc/netforce' 'C-m'` .

Thanks for the help before.